# How to optimize a batch pivotization?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a datetime list (which for some reason I call it column `date`) containing over 1k datetime.

```
adates:2017.10.20T00:02:35.650 2017.10.20T01:57:13.454 ...
```

For each of these dates I need to select the data from some table, then pivotize by a column `t` i.e. expiry, add the corresponding `date` datetime as column to the pivotized table and stitch together the pivotization for all the dates. Note that I should be able to identify which pivotization corresponds to a date and that's why I do it one by one:

```
fPivot:{[adate;accypair]
     t1:select from volatilitysurface_smile where date=adate,ccypair=accypair;
     mycols:`atm`s10c`s10p`s25c`s25p;
     t2:`t xkey 0!exec mycols#(stype!mid) by t:t from t1;
     t3:`t xkey select distinct t,tenor,xi,volofvol,delta_type,spread from t1;
     result:ej[`t;t2;t3];
     :result}
```

I then call this function for every datetime `adates` as follows:

```
raze {[accypair;adate] `date xcols update date:adate from fPivot[adate;accypair] }[`EURCHF] @/: adates;
```

this takes about 90s. I wonder if there is a better way e.g. do a big pivotization rather than running one pivotization per date and then stitching it all together. The big issue I see is that I have no apparent way to include the  `date` attribute as part of the pivotization and the `date` can not be lost otherwise I can't reconciliate the results.

Comment: The data you have provided in `adates` is of type datetime not timestamp. A timestamp in kdb looks like `2017.11.28D12:55:47.354335000`. Note the `D` separator between date and time, compared to the `T` separator in datetime types.

Comment: Correct sorry my bad, updating ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I solved the issue by creating a batch version of the pivotization that keeps the date (datetime) table field when doing the group by bit needed to pivot i.e. `by t:t from ...` to `by date:date,t:t from ...`. It went from 90s down to 150 milliseconds.

```
fBatchPivot:{[adates;accypair]
    t1:select from volatilitysurface_smile where date in adates,ccypair=accypair;
    mycols:`atm`s10c`s10p`s25c`s25p;
    t2:`date`t xkey 0!exec mycols#(stype!mid) by date:date,t:t from t1;
    t3:`date`t xkey select distinct date,t,tenor,xi,volofvol,delta_type,spread from t1;
    result:0!(`date`t xasc t2 ij t3);
    :result}
```

Comment: Looks good, you could accept it as the answer to wrap up this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you havent been to the wiki page on [pivoting](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/) then it may be a good start. There is a section on a [general pivoting function](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/#a-very-general-pivot-function-and-an-example) that makes some claims to being somewhat efficient:

> One user reports:
>
> This is able to pivot a whole day of real quote data, about 25 million
>   quotes over about 4000 syms and an average of 5 levels per sym, in a
>   little over four minutes.

As for general comments, I would say that the [`ej`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#ej-equi-join) is unnecessary as it is a more general version of [`ij`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#ij-ijf-inner-join), allowing you to specify the key column. As both `t2` and `t3` have the same keying I would instead use:

```
t2 ij t3
```

Which may give you a very minor performance boost.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for the answer. Yes I have been to that wiki that's the way I build the pivotization. I tried once using that function but it is very complex specially figuring out what f and g should be but indeed it looks promissing. Your answer would be complete if you could show how to call that general purpose pivot for the OP :)

Comment: I can try give it a go if you give an example `volatilitysurface_smile` table or even just the schema for the table. Editing it into the question may help anyone else coming along to formulate an answer too.